# Codable with NSOrdered set?

Tags: swift, codable

It looks like NSOrdered does not support the the Codable protol.
I'm using codable to parse data with alamofire and coredata.What is the way to achieve that please ? Txs for help ! :)

```
 self.photos = try values.decodeIfPresent([Photo].self, forKey: .photos)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON does not have ordered sets. It just has arrays. So you need to convert the array into an NSOrderedSet by calling its initializer:

```
self.photos = NSOrderedSet(array:
    try values.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .photos) ?? [])
```

(That said, I would strongly recommend getting rid of NSOrderedSet. It's a mess of a data structure, and plays poorly with Swift. You're almost always better wrapping up an Array and just controlling when you insert into it. If you believe there's a performance difference, you should do a lot of profiling on your actual data before assuming that.)